# Can't modify registry user access

Tags: .net, vb.net, registry, registrykey

I'm trying to make a generic function to set the registry user permissions.

The problem is, if I deny the fullcontrol acces of a key using the code then If I will allow it again it throws an exception when is trying to read the key at this line:

```
    Dim RK As RegistryKey = RootKey.OpenSubKey(KeyPath, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.ChangePermissions Or RegistryRights.ReadKey)
```

I call the procedure like this:

```
 RegEdit.Set_UserAccess_Key("hkcu\appevents", RegistryRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Deny)
```

That is working, and after that I call this:

```
 RegEdit.Set_UserAccess_Key("hkcu\appevents", RegistryRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow)
```

The exception when I try to allow a previously denied permission:

```
Requested registry access denied

Acceso denegado al Registro solicitado.
```

This is the code:

```
''' <summary>
''' Modify the User permissions of a registry key.
''' </summary>
Public Shared Sub Set_UserAccess_Key(ByVal RegKey As String, _
                                     ByVal RegUserAccess As RegistryRights, _
                                     ByVal AccessType As AccessControlType, _
                                     Optional ByVal UserName As String = Nothing)

    If UserName = Nothing Then UserName = Environment.UserDomainName & "\" & Environment.UserName

    Dim RootKey As RegistryKey = Get_Root_Key(RegKey) ' Registrykey.Currentuser
    Dim KeyPath As String = Get_Key_Path(RegKey) ' AppEvents

    Dim RS As New RegistrySecurity()
    Dim RK As RegistryKey = RootKey.OpenSubKey(KeyPath, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.ChangePermissions Or RegistryRights.ReadKey)

    RS.AddAccessRule(New RegistryAccessRule(UserName, RegUserAccess, InheritanceFlags.None, PropagationFlags.None, AccessType))
    RK.SetAccessControl(RS)
    RK = RootKey.OpenSubKey(KeyPath, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegUserAccess)
    RK.SetAccessControl(RS)

End Sub
```

Comment: The question and also the asnwers of "possible duplicate" has nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a small program some time ago to grant full access to a given `Registry Key`. It did always work fine. Its code is equivalent to yours except for:

```
RS.AddAccessRule(New RegistryAccessRule(UserName, RegistryRights.CreateSubKey Or RegistryRights.Delete Or RegistryRights.ExecuteKey Or RegistryRights.FullControl Or RegistryRights.ReadKey Or RegistryRights.SetValue Or RegistryRights.WriteKey, AccessControlType.Allow))
```

Not sure if there is any change with respect to your code (you are using variables whose content I cannot know). In any case, note that this app never accessed the given key right after having changed the security level. The process was: first execution to set full access to the key; a different execution to access the modified key.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the content is the same except I use the propagation flags, but I've tried to use instead your line of code without flags and still not working, but thanks

Comment: @ElektroHacker as said, this code works and I have tested it under different conditions. Try to not access the key right after changing the security level. Re-run the program or make sure that you close all the connections with the Registry before accessing it and should work.